# Need to link only one Accordion panel through href AND maintain collapse functionality

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, panel

Here's a fiddle of the functionality that I'd like:

https://jsfiddle.net/jo6cfr7b/2/

I have three accordion panels. Two of them contain a submenu, one of them contains nothing but instead links elsewhere on click (using href).

When I try and link through href on my first accordion group, I lose the ability to collapse all panels on click. It just doesn't work anymore.

```
<div> 
<div id="accordion"> <!-- accordion 1 -->
   <div class="panel">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionOne">
       Need this to link outside
     </a>
    <div id="accordionOne">
     </div>
  </div>

   <div class="panel">  <!-- accordion 2 -->
     <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionTwo">
       Collapsible Accordion 2
     </a>
     <div id="accordionTwo" class="collapse">
       <div class="panel-body">
         Change does not roll in on the wheels of inevitability,
         but comes through continuous struggle.
         And so we must straighten our backs and work for
         our freedom. A man can't ride you unless your back is bent.
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

    <div class="panel">  <!-- accordion 3 -->
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordionThree">
        Collapsible Accordion 3
      </a>

      <div id="accordionThree" class="collapse">
        <!-- panel body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          You must take personal responsibility.
          You cannot change the circumstances,
          the seasons, or the wind, but you can change yourself.
          That is something you have charge of.
        </div>

      </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**TLDR**; How can I maintain the collapse functionality when clicking any of the accordion group anchors, while being able to link externally on the first accordion panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `data-target` and `href`...

Just use `data-target=""` for the collapsing behavior, and `href=".."` for the external on the first collapse link.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#accordionOne" href="/">
       Need this to link to another page (but collapse any currently open submenus)
</a>
```

[Codeply Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/QrNf4Va5G6)